# How do I prevent data from resetting upon clicking anchor tag

Tags: php, html, url, get

For school a few friends and I have to make a website where a PHP script takes data from the URL with the $_GET variable.

We can retrieve data from the URL like: `index.php?data=set`.

Here is what I the part I'm not sure how to make. We want this data to be set when clicking an anchor tag like:
`<a href="?sortby=rating">Rating</a>`
and the want to be able to set more data with another anchor tag without clearing the data from the previous tag so the url can become something like: `index.php?data=set&sortby=rating`

We all have the feeling this can be done very easily with pure html but we just haven't been able to find how to do it. Unless we have to just write PHP code that alters the link in an anchor tag according to if there has already data been set or not and then change `<a href="?sortby=rating">Rating</a>` to `<a href="?sortby=rating&data=set">Rating</a>` using PHP.

I apologize if I poorly explained anything and/or if this a really simple thing to do, we just haven't been able to figure out what to look for on google. If the only way to do it is using PHP then we can figure it out, if not, please tell me how to do it correctly.

Thank you

Comment: _"...we have to just write PHP code that alters the link in an anchor tag according to if there has already data been set or not..."_ - precisely this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` global will help you to retrieve all your query data, then you have to decide if :
it's a new query parameter and you have to add it to your query string
or it's an existing parameter which you need to update it.

```
<?php
   function query_stack($query_name,$query_value){
       $filled = "?";
       foreach ($_REQUEST as $param => $value)
          if($param != $query_name) $filled .= "${param}=${value}&";  // it's new key so we add it to our stack
       return $filled."${query_name}=${query_value}"; // we have to update/reassign value of this key
   }
?>


<a href="<?php echo query_stack('sort','stars') ?>"><b>Sort By:</b> Stars</a><hr>
<a href="<?php echo query_stack('sort','date') ?>"><b>Sort By:</b> Date</a><hr>
<a href="<?php echo query_stack('view','asc') ?>"><b>View:</b> Ascending</a><hr>
<a href="<?php echo query_stack('view','des') ?>"><b>View:</b> Descending</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this has solved my issue.